# SQL Server: select distinct mon-yyyy format output sorty by descending order

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `datetime` column in a table with following data:

```
2011-03-23
2011-04-19
2011-04-26
2011-05-26
```

I want to select distinct `mon-yyyy` format output ordered by report date descending. We need to select only one column in the SQL statement

This SQL works, but I want to order by `ReportDate` column

```
SELECT  distinct SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
        SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),8,4 ) 
  FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
```

**output**

```
Apr-2011
Mar-2011
May-2011
```

This SQL gives an error:

```
SELECT  distinct SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
        SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),8,4 ) 
  FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
  order by ReportDate
```

**Error:**

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified.

What is the best SQL query to get the output I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
with testdata as
(
  select cast('2011-03-23' as datetime) as d
union all
  select cast('2011-04-19' as datetime)
union all
  select cast('2011-04-26' as datetime)
union all
  select cast('2011-05-26' as datetime)
)
SELECT DATENAME(month,d)+'-'+DATENAME(year,d)
FROM testdata
GROUP BY DATEPART(year,d), DATEPART(month,d), DATENAME(month,d),DATENAME(year,d)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year,d), DATEPART(month,d)
```

---

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,ReportDate)+'-'+DATENAME(year,ReportDate)
FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
GROUP BY DATEPART(year,ReportDate), DATEPART(month,ReportDate), DATENAME(month,ReportDate),DATENAME(year,ReportDate)
ORDER BY DATEPART(year,ReportDate), DATEPART(month,ReportDate)
```

Comment: This didn't give the result I want. I expect something like this `SELECT DISTINCT right(convert(varchar,ReportDate,106),8)
FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
ORDER BY ReportDate desc`

Comment: You want it ordered in the date order?

Answer (score 2):

You can use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT like this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
        SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),8,4 ) 
FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
GROUP BY SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
          SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),8,4 )
```

With order by on ReportDate desc, using row_number() instead of group by.

```
select substring(convert(varchar, Env.ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
          substring(convert(varchar, Env.ReportDate, 100),8,4 )
from (select
        ReportDate,
        row_number() over(partition by datepart(year, ReportDate), datepart(month, ReportDate)
                          order by (select 1)) as rn
      from [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]) as Env    
where Env.rn = 1
order by Env.ReportDate desc
```

Comment: from this SQL how can I sort result by descending order.

Answer (score 2):

I think there was a similar question here recently, which I can't find now, but the answer was something to this effect:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ReportDate, 100), 1, 3) + '-' +
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ReportDate, 100), 8, 4)
FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
GROUP BY
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ReportDate, 100), 1, 3),
  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar, ReportDate, 100), 8, 4)
ORDER BY MIN(ReportDate)
```

Also, while the way you've chosen to present the output in the format of `mmm-yyyy` is basically fine, I would probably do the same slightly differently. Here:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(DATENAME(month, ReportDate), 3) + '-' +
  DATENAME(year,  ReportDate)
FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
GROUP BY
  DATENAME(month, ReportDate),
  DATENAME(year,  ReportDate)
ORDER BY MIN(ReportDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind an extra column in the result set, then this will work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), ReportDate, 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YYYY],
    RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), ReportDate, 120) /* [YYYY-MM]*/ DESC) AS r_order
FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
ORDER BY r_order DESC
```

<del>If you don't want to provide a column alias for the MMM-YYYY (which you can then use in the ORDER BY), can't you just do **ORDER BY 1 DESC**?

    SELECT DISTINCT
      SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
      SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),8,4 )
    FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
    ORDER BY 1 DESC


Or just add a column alias:

    SELECT DISTINCT
      SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),1,3) +'-'+
      SUBSTRING (convert(varchar, ReportDate, 100),8,4 ) AS ReportDate
    FROM [EnvelopsDB].[dbo].[Envelopes]
    ORDER BY ReportDate DESC</del>

Comment: ah - I see. This wasn't clear from the original question.  I re-read and see that part now.